# SQL query for displaying count if same name comes in adjacent row it should show the count else 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table `tb1` with columns `id,name`,

if same name comes in adjacent row it should display the count count else 1

For eg:

```
id                name

1                 sam

2                 jose

3                 sam

4                 sam

5                 dev

6                 jose
```

Result want to be

```
name                 counts

 sam                   1

 jose                  1

 sam                   2

 dev                   1

 jose                  1
```

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a combination with a sub query, "COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION", and row_number():

```
--DROP TABLE #Test;
SELECT id = IDENTITY(INT,1,1), name INTO #Test FROM 
(
    SELECT name = 'sam' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'jose' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'sam ' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'sam ' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'sam ' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dev ' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dev ' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'jose' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'sam ' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'sam ' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'jose' 
) a;

GO

WITH GetEndID AS (
    SELECT *
    , EndID =(SELECT MIN(id) FROM #Test b WHERE b.name != a.name AND b.id > a.id)
    FROM #Test a
), GetCount AS
(
    SELECT 
    *
    , NameCount = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EndID)
    , OrderPrio = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EndID ORDER BY id)
    FROM GetEndID
)
SELECT id, name, NameCount FROM GetCount WHERE OrderPrio = 1 ORDER BY id;
```

[image]

Comment: in id=3,4,5 the results is same sam 3. how can it be neglected.

Comment: @shyamev: I have updated the answer for you, duplicates will be  removed as you intended.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jarle Bjornbeth

Answer (score 3):

Check out this one :(SELF JOIN)

```
create table #sampele(id int,name varchar(50))

insert into #sampele values(1,'sam')
insert into #sampele values(2,'jose')
insert into #sampele values(3,'sam')
insert into #sampele values(4,'sam')
insert into #sampele values(5,'dev')
insert into #sampele values(6,'jose')


select a.id,a.name,case when a.name = b.name then 2 else 1 end as cnt from
#sampele a 
left outer join
#sampele b
on a.id = b.id+1
```

[image]

Comment: Hai karthick the problem is this is just a sample if the the 3 or 4 adjustent has same value the coubt want to be 3 or 4

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct a.name,case when a.name = b.name then 2 else 1 end as cnt from
tb1 a 
left outer join
tb1 b
on a.id = b.id+1
```

sQlfiddle

[Click to see running](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17ca6a/5)

Comment: hai ali this is just a sample if the 3 or 4 adjucent has the same value i need the count to be 3 or 4 not 2

Comment: yes while writing this answer I thought of this, will check and edit it.